# How to configure VMware Workstation to use the physical internal PC speaker?

Tags: windows, audio, vmware, vmware-workstation, speakers

Good morning/afternoon/evening everybody. Currently I'm messing around with a particular malware that is capable of making use of the PC speaker. As I really need the host internal PC speaker to work instead of the virtual one, I'm asking that question. Is it really possible? And no, the volume mixer won't work as there's no PC speaker configurator present. Thanks in advance.

P.S. I tried asking for help on the VMware forum. No response.

Comment: Just to verify I understand your question.  You want VMWare to be able to use your the mono speaker connected directly to your motherboard?

Comment: Yes. Just what I need.

Comment: Your host OS doesn't even have access to that speaker.  It isn't a physical device that can be address, which means VMWare cannot acess it, which means your VM cannot use it

Comment: That's strange, because it actually does have access. For example, a program called BaWaMi is capable of playing MIDI music through the motherboard speaker. Se theoretically VMware also should have access to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from version 12, Workstation [stopped to support host PC Speaker](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/563883). Guest PC speaker operations are emulated on the appropriate host auduo playback endpoint.

If you want to silence guest beeps, use "mks.NoBeep=true" in the .vmx file (for a particular VM) or in config.ini (for all VMs).

Comment: Ah man. What a disappointment. Thank you anyway. Looks like I gotta download the 11th version.

Comment: @BiostarII Why isn't the emulated PC speaker sufficient?

Comment: @jamesdlin Because I need the physical one.

Comment: @BiostarII Sorry, but that still doesn't answer why.  If the PC speaker is properly emulated, then it shouldn't matter whether audio is coming from your host's PC speaker or from your sound card. (Unless, say, you don't have speakers connected to your host's sound card.) If the PC speaker is *not* emulated properly, then okay, but that seems like a bug.

Comment: @jamesdlin I need the physical one for an experiment. That's all.